# good output/executer for discord.py

Tags: python, command, executor

each time I'm running a command, the command doesn't give an error to the python executor. It just breaks out of it.

Is there any better executor that yall could recommend?

Comment: What sort of *error* do you have in mind?

Comment: Also, what do you believe is an *executor* in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it shows an error, sometimes it doesn't. If a command doesn't work, but the console doesn't output anything, you might want to try the following:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = "token"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%')

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError): # Checks if the error was when a command failed
        print(error) # Prints out the error in the console

client.run(token)
```

This will print out the error if the command fails.